# Facebook comment-count always showing 0

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

i've been trying to implement the facebook comments-count feature on my website (using html and C#).
it's a dynamic page, created from the code behind like so:

```
tmpGuides = tmpGuides + "<img src=\"images/comments.gif\" alt=\"\" style=\"vertical-align: baseline;\" />" + "<fb:comments-count href=http://www.someexamplesite.com/article.aspx?=1909/> </fb:comments-count> ";
```

it always shows 0 instead of the real amount of comments.

i'm working from my local machine now, but i tried uploading the code to production and it still doesn't work. I also tried url encoding the address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do seem to have the right syntax. Are you sure there are definitely comments on the url you are using?

Following the [documentation on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), under the heading "**How do I access the number of comments left of my page?**", you can see the code below works for "example.com":

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
<fb:comments-count href="http://example.com/"></fb:comments-count> awesome comments
```

If you can get try get it working for example.com then you know that you don't have a problem with your code and it is more likely that there are no comments on the url you are specifying.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I tried using the js you sent but I then I didn't get a number at all (instead of a 0). I tried adding a &appId=1111111111 after the #xfbml and it still didn't work.

Comment: That is strange. I just tried it again and I got "42721 awesome comments". Can you try change example.com to a number of high profile sites and see if you get any figure at all?

Comment: You are right. it does show a number when I use example.com (25 comments). When I try a page that has comments for sure on my site, it shows 0 comments. Could it be a conflict with the fb login component on the masterpage?

Comment: @Yuval can you try the link below replacing facebook.com with your url please? `https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='www.facebook.com'`

Comment: That's funny, I put my address in the query and i get 0 in the count (I tried different sites and got good results). you can check out the url and see that i do have comments on the page(and i'm not crazy :) ) https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27bekaloot.co.il/article.aspx?id=1909%27

Comment: Hi @Yuval, if you put a capital a in for article, e.g. Article.aspx it should return the results. The url you specified in your fb:like tag has a capital A.