# Facebook Graph API - Android - URL comment count is wrong

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have read this "[Facebook comment-count always showing 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324590/facebook-comment-count-always-showing-0)" but it isn't my case.

I use graph API for android to count number of comments on a url link. Just look a simple example:

1 - Use graph explorer: [Press this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%3Ffields%3Dshare%7Bcomment_count%7D%26id%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2Fcomments%2F&version=v2.2). You will see the result is **"comment_count": 47** at this time, and a line ***"id": "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/"*** that content the link we count.

2 - But when I use android facebook graph to query the link like this:

```
String linkt = "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/";
String graphLink = "/v2.2/?format=json&fields=share{comment_count}&id=" + linkt;
```

I got the result `{"id":"https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/plugins\/comments\/?format=json","share":{"comment_count":0}}`

Do you see the "?format=json" was automatically added to my url. So the result is always 0. Because it a wrong url.

Thank you for all help.

Comment: I used the graph like this: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/?fields=share{comment_count}&id=<YOUR_URL>. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "&" after my link to separate with "?format=j", then it worked.